# Rename dataframe columns based on values in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one data frame which has one column & two records in it.

DF1=

```
Name 
M_D
ABC123
```

I have another dataframe which has two columns. I need to rename second dataframe columns with two values in first data frame.

DF2=

```
   PQR  LMN
   111  345
   456  999
```

I want DF2 as below

```
   M_D  ABC123
   111  345
   456  999
```

Thanks

Comment: will you know the column names of either data.frame at design time?  Or will both always be unknown/different?

Comment: As of now i know , but i think it might change in future as it is read from a monthly file , so if any dynamic approach will also be great , otherwise I can some how hard code it.

Comment: names(DF2) <- DF1$Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access values for column names for `DF2` using `$` or `[[` operator on `DF1`. Since OP has mentioned that he doesn't even know the column names of `DF1`, an option could  be as:

```
names(DF2) <- DF1[,1]
DF2
#  M_D ABC123
#1 111    345
#2 456    999

#OR
names(DF2) <- DF1[[1]]

#OR
names(DF2) <- DF1$Name
```

**Note:** `names(DF2) <- DF1[1]` will not work as `DF1[1]` is still of type `data.frame` and `names<-` expects a `vector`.

**Data:**

```
DF2 <- read.table(text = 
"PQR  LMN
111  345
456  999",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF1 <- read.table(text = 
"Name 
M_D
ABC123",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above, I recommend hardcoding it with something like [`dplyr::rename()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html).

```
DF2 <- DF2 %>% 
  dplyr::rename(
    M_D       = PQR,
    ABC123    = LMN
  )
```

In my experience, you shouldn't really trust that collaborators will give you the same dataset structure each time.  This will throw an error if they've changed the column names (this is good --you want to be alerted to the problem early in the pipeline).  If they've change the column order, `dplyr::rename()` will handle it gracefully & correctly.

Consider additional [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) tools like [checkmate](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=checkmate) or [testit](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=testit) to verify the column characteristics match your expectations (*e.g.*, the `PQR`/`M_D` column is an integer with values between 0 and 5).

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the length of DF1$Name is the same as the number of columns of DF2

```
colnames(DF2) <- DF1$Name
```